# Why does a DME ground station wait 50 microseconds?

Tags: navigation, navaids

The FAA says that a DME ground station sends a response exactly 50 microseconds after having received an interrogation from an aircraft. For what reason is there a 50 microsecond delay?

Comment: An important question is: does it say (and mean) **typically**, or is that a **specified delay**?

Comment: if milliseconds is a typo, **why doesn't someone edit it?**

Comment: It would appear that the "typically" here is totally incorrect.  (See Henning below.)  Someone should edit it.

Comment: @JoeBlow: At Math.SE, where I spend most of my time, we're reluctant to edit questions to remove misconceptions by the OP. Clearing up the misconceptions should rather happen in _answers_, because getting that cleared up could be the entire point for the asker (here the OP might be asking because he thinks 50 ms is a strangely long delay to be using -- who knows?), and having it pointed out in the form of an edit is much less visible than an actual answer. I don't know if the standards are differently on aviation.SE, but this is why _I_ didn't edit.

Comment: that's an interesting policy; understood. pedagogically, it makes sense.  I'm troubled by Wrong Text going out in to google though, you know  :O

Comment: @JoeBlow As Henning's answer mentions, the delay can be reduced when used with ILS systems in order to make the distance appear to be at the runway threshold rather than at the actual antenna of the DME ground station, so 'typically' seems accurate. For exact details of the DME system, see chapter 4 from [FAA AC 00-31A](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC00-31a.pdf).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't agree Reirab, you'd never use "typically" to describe an exactly specified part of a system (when it's deliberately varied shorter you're still exactly "simulating" that precision spec-specified time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the purpose of the 50 microsecond delay is to eliminate the possibility of uncoordinated operation when the aircraft is very close to the ground station

From [AVweb - DME Basics](http://www.avweb.com/news/avionics/183230-1.html?redirected=1)

---

Addendum

I have not found a clear explanation for what is meant by "uncoordinated operation" in the context of DME. What follows is speculation:

If you look at patents related to DME, it seems this predictable delay ensured that the initial transmission from the aircraft would have been completely received before the reply was transmitted by the base-station and received at the aircraft.

I believe a DME response has to match the pattern of the DME interrogation so that the receiver in the aircraft can identify which response to apply timing to if multiple DME-equipped aircraft are in range.

The pulse spacing is 12 µs<sup>1</sup> and this is the same order of magnitude as the round-trip transmission time at 1 mile. A single DME interrogation contains several pulses. It may be difficult to design ground station equipment that can start transmitting a matching response if it has not yet received the pattern of data it has to reproduce. The alternative would be to start transmitting the response as soon as possible after detecting the end of receipt of a valid DME interrogation.

There are delays in processing within the ground station equipment which may vary (at least from station to station depending on equipment) and which therefore need to be made constant for accurate distances to be calculated by the airborne receiver. Any variations would be more significant at closer distances.

It might also be easier to design airborne equipment if it does not have to start receiving the response before it has finished transmitting the interrogation.

---

References

1. [US Patent 3226714](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US3226714)
2. [PPRuNe discussion](http://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-161950.html)

I believe DME was invented around 1944-45 but cannot find any patents that early. There are quite a few patents on this subject.

Comment: Although it does not provide the detail, this should be the accepted answer.  Specifically, the "uncoordinated operation" would occur if the transmitter was still sending the second interrogation pulse when the first reply was received from an aircraft at close range.  50 µs corresponds to approx 4 NM within which, without the delay, aircraft would show unreliable readings.

Comment: @Simon: It is not the correct answer. The DME interrogator on board determines the slant range by measuring the time for the signal to reach the ground station (transponder), plus the time for the ground station to send the response (call this one T), plus the time for the response to reach the on board interrogator. Then the interrogator which is interested only in the time for the signal to travel back and forth, needs to remove T. If T is variable (dependent of the station design) then it is not possible. Hence T must be standardized.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised this "reference" is just from a pretty crappy, 20 year old general-interest magazine article! Sorry I at first commented that it seemed to be factual.

Comment: Hi mins. Do you have an actual reference that states the 50ms is standardised.  What's the allowed error for equipment makers?  (if it's an ISO standard or something, it's inconceivable these days it wouldn't be given with an error range.)

Comment: @JoeBlow: The 50 µs (not ms) is standardized in ICAO Annex 10, volume I, section 3.5.4.4. (This doesn't seem to be publicly available, but there are pirated copies floating around if you google hard enough). The specified tolerance is ±1 µs (section 3.5.4.5), which corresponds to an error of 500 feet in the result. Most installed DMEs do better than that.

Comment: "ICAO Annex 10, volume I, section 3.5.4.4" that is **awesome**

Comment: should surely be in your answer

Comment: I didn't accept this answer, because the phrase "uncoordinated operation" seems unclear to me.

Comment: @HenningMakholm According to [FAA Advisory Circular 00-31A](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC00-31a.pdf), the 50 +/- 1 us number is outdated. This AC states a specification of 56 +/- 0.25 us and changes the definition to be from rising edge of the first pulse of the interrogation to rising edge of the first pulse of the response, rather than the second pulse of each. See paragraph 131 on page 22.

Comment: @reirab: Yes, the ICAO specification just provides minimum recommendations that apply globally, but a country is allowed to aim for better precision with its own navaids. DME/P as specified for the Microwave Landing System has even smaller tolerances, down to a few tens of nanoseconds. (Since one cycle of the carrier frequency is about one nanosecond, this must call for some serious RF engineering -- in addition to a more precise redefinition of when exactly the "rising edge" is!)

Comment: Note that the 56 µs is between the first pulses in Y channels only. Since the _second_ pulses still have a separation of 50 µs in all modes (even though it's not primarily specified separation), I kept my discussion in terms of that in an attempt to avoid confusion.

Comment: As for the edit: The ground station _must not_ begin transmitting until it has received both pulses and verified that they have the right spacing. Otherwise it might mistake extraneous pulses for interrogations -- each interrogation frequency is shared between an X-channel and an Y-channel, which are distinguished by the separation between the interrogation pulses. Even worse, the same frequency carries _replies_ for a different Y channel, so two stations might end up responding to each other's pulses indefinitely unless they wait until they have decoded the second pulse.

Comment: the sentence from "AVWeb" is utter crap and should be deleted.  (I don't know why you haven't deleted it, RGB!)  the rest of the answer is fantastic.

Comment: @Joe: That sentence appears in several sources. When I can find something better I'll edit that part. Still looking.

Answer (score 23):

The delay is not 50 *milliseconds*, but 50 *microseconds*.

It takes some time for the ground equipment to decode the incoming signal, decide it needs to reply, and fire up its transmitter. In order for the distance measurement to be reliable, this inevitable delay needs to be precisely defined and the same for all DME stations. It also gives the airborne interrogation some minimal time to shut down its transmitter and start listening even when it's right on top of the ground station.

50 µs must have felt like a suitable interval to standardize on, **long enough** for it to be reasonably possible to engineer the ground stations to meet it (given the technology of the time the design was made), yet **short enough** that one DME station can service an acceptable number of aircraft without needing to handle overlapping delays between different interrogations.

The standard delay also means that a DME station used for ILS can be located midway between the runway's thresholds and adjusted such that aircraft see the distance to the threshold rather than the distance to the physical antenna, by reducing the delay appropriately. (Such a DME does not give useful readings for aircraft not aligned with the runway).

Note, by the way, that the 50 µs is the time between receiving the *second* pulse of an interrogation pulse-pair and transmitting the *second* pulse of the resply. So the ground station actually has to *start* transmitting the reply less than 50 µs after it knows it has received a complete interrogation. For Y channels where there are 30 µs between the two reply pulses, the ground station *actually* has only 20 µs to react.

Comment: A small point: the overlapping issue would be irrelevant, I think. If the delay was (let's say) 20 seconds, it would be utterly trivial to still send each one out exactly 20 seconds after the relevant arrival, even if as it happened many were arriving at the same time. In other words regarding this issue: *"handle overlapping delays between different interrogations"*, it's quite true the soft3are engineers would have to "handle" that but (A) it makes utterly no difference what the specified delay is, and (B) as it happens, it is trivial anyway.

Comment: {Any obscure racetrack bugs which would appear - would appear anyway regardless of the set delay.}

Comment: @JoeBlow: It is indeed _possible_ to handle overlapping delay period if you have a computer to keep track of them -- not utterly trivial, because the exact timings of replies have to be executed with something approaching nanosecond precision, but certainly doable. However, remember that the system dates back to the 1950s. At that time you _wouldn't_ have a computer around to control the ground station; the delay would be implemented with analog circuits. In that setting, keeping several different delays active at the same time would be an entirely different problem.

Comment: @JoeBlow: As for delaying 20 seconds, quite independently of making the _ground_ station do it, that would place ridiculous demands on the clock stability of the _airborne_ equipment. Each part-per-million of clock drift would cause a measurement error of more than 3 NM.

Comment: Hi Henning - re 1950, fair enoughL I have no clue what they had then.  (It seems strange that we're still using concepts from 70 years ago? Wouldn't this have been updated somehow?)  Just regarding the 20 purely-an-example seconds.  It's still unclear whether the signal is meant o come out **precisely** 50 ms afterwards, or is the point of the guideline that it should be "around" 50ms .. or indeed does it mean "up to 50ms, the faster the better".  Nobody has been able to answer this.

Comment: @JoeBlow: It is _precisely_ 50 µs (still not 50 ms, which is one thousand times longer than 50 µs). The principle of DME is that the aircraft measures how long it takes for the reply to arrive, and multiplies that with the speed of light. If the ground station replies with _less_ than the specified 50 µs of delay, the aircraft will think it is _closer_ to the DME that it actually is. For example, responding 12 µs too early will lead to a reading one nautical mile too short.

Comment: @JoeBlow: As for "70 years ago": The existing protocol works, and changing it would require all aircraft to carry receivers for two different systems in a transition period -- it could be years or decades until the ground stations that implement the _old_ protocols had all been replaced. The cost of this would be phenomenal, so a change won't happen unless it provides concrete **benefits**. Not just because "we might have chosen a different number if we started over from scratch today".

Comment: I see, it's precisely 50 ms.  (I am using here ms for microseconds, as in lol or btw.  I'm guessing you are using the "official" SI unit, which is also nice.) **Thanks for clearing that up.**  You can see that the "typically" in the question was wildly confusing!

Comment: Just purely BTW.  *"short enough that one DME station can service an acceptable number of aircraft without needing to handle overlapping delays between different interrogations"*  Note that: if you make D shorter you are **less likely** to get racetracks (simple statistics), but anyone building such a system, would, **absolutely** have to be able to handle racetracks. It's possible in the analog era (or even today) the policy is that you throw away racetracks (items that arrive "during D") - and that's fine if it's the policy - but it seems dubious that would be the policy.

Comment: I feel that the first sentence of your answer should be... "To clarify, the delay is precisely, and must be precisely, 50 µs."

Comment: @JoeBlow I would assume that the primary reason that the DME system is not designed to attempt to keep multiple overlapping timers to reply to different aircraft is because there is only one single radio channel available to each DME ground station. If it tried to keep multiple timers and respond to different aircraft it would run into two problems: 1) The reply pulses would probably need to overlap, which isn't possible and 2) The aircraft would both accept the first response, resulting in the 2nd aircraft indicating closer than it actually is.

Comment: @reirab: The aircraft is supposed to send out a stream of interrogations at randomized times and only believe replies that _consistently_ arrive the same amount of time after each interrogation. (The FAA document you found even specifies that a ground station must send out a steady stream of random "ghost" replies if it doesn't have enough interrogations to respond to, such that this feature in the airborne receivers will be exercised all the time).

Comment: Right, I was just about to explain this in terms of how "GT3" works to synchronise the players  :)  It's the same fundamental computer science concept used to (say) decide on "who should be the server" in something like Bonjour on your mac, or whatever.  Obviously today every aircraft device would just have digital IDs (hell, you'd just log in to a web server on the ground station :) ) .. engineers don't have to be clever like this any more.  It's a bit like, "traditional" automatic gearboxes are really clever; now they're just robotized, which is nothing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, that's true. That would solve the second problem of an airborne transponder not knowing whether a given reply was for it or not, but it still doesn't resolve the issue of there being only one channel on which a given DME ground station can transmit, which still generally limits it to only talking to one aircraft at a time. It can't send a response pulse to two aircraft at once (without doing some kind of multiplexing whose complexity would not have been worthwhile back then.) Even now, though, channel arbitration is still an issue all wireless protocols must solve.

Comment: @reirab: The channel arbitration protocol is that every aircraft sends interrogations at random intervals and is supposed to be resilient enough to keep functioning if some of them are lost due to collisions. It takes less than 0.1 ms for the ground station to respond to one interrogation and be ready for the next one, so as long as there are less than about 100 aircraft actively using a given DME (with at most 30 interrogations per second each, once they're in "tracking mode" and have some idea of which range to expect), collisions will be rare enough to cope with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right. That's why I said it wouldn't have been worthwhile to attempt a more complex arbitration scheme using some form of multiplexing. The current "don't respond to the second interrogation" scheme was good enough and much more simple to implement.